# JSF 2.0 seems to ignore filter

Tags: jsf

I am using JSF to create some user authorization/check before entering specific pages under secure/ directory but without success... I tried both with phaselistener and filter but stil... Well any help is very welcome.

I am using Eclipse Juno.

My web.xml is as follows:

```
<filter>
<filter-name>AuthorizationFilter</filter-name>
<filter-class>login.security.AuthorizationFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>AuthorizationFilter</filter-name>
<url-pattern>/secure/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping> 
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

AuthorizationFilter looks like this:

```
public class AuthorizationFilter implements Filter {
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain  chain) throws ServletException, IOException {    
HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
login.Login_bean login_bean = (login.Login_bean)
req.getSession().getAttribute("username");
if (login_bean != null && login_bean.isLoggedIn()) {
chain.doFilter(request, response);
} else {
HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;
res.sendRedirect(req.getContextPath() + "/index.xhtml");
}
}
```

With overriden destroy() and init. It is copy/past from several sites around.

Login_bean is managed and session scoped and when user/pass pair are correct i got this running:

```
if(password.equals(dbpassword)){
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().put("username", username);
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().put("email", email);
this.visibleLogout="true";
this.visibleLogin="false";
return "valid";
}
```

And directory structure looks like:

```
WebContent
-> secure
    -> projects.xhtml
-> index.xhtml
```

index.xhtml where i want to prohibit access:

```
<p:menuitem id="projects" value="#{menuBean.projectsValue}" action="#{menuBean.navTo(projects)}" icon="ui-icon-circle-triangle-e" />.
```

and finally
menuBean.navTo() is:

```
public String navTo(String whereTo)
{
return "/secure/projects";
}
```

I have hit a wall somehow.. even if change url-pattern to /faces/secure/* i still i am forwarded to projects.xhtml

full faces-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<faces-config xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_1.xsd"
    version="2.1">


    <managed-bean>
        <managed-bean-name>languageBean</managed-bean-name>
        <managed-bean-class>languageControl.LanguageBean</managed-bean-class>
        <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
    </managed-bean>

    <managed-bean>
        <managed-bean-name>menuBean</managed-bean-name>
        <managed-bean-class>menuControl.MenuBean</managed-bean-class>
        <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
    </managed-bean>

    <navigation-rule>
        <description>login_rule</description>
        <from-view-id>/index.xhtml</from-view-id>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-action>#{login_bean.checkValidUser}</from-action>
            <from-outcome>valid</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/nav.xhtml</to-view-id>
        </navigation-case>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-action>#{login_bean.checkValidUser}</from-action>
            <from-outcome>invalid</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/index.xhtml</to-view-id>
        </navigation-case>
    </navigation-rule>

    <application>
        <locale-config>
            <default-locale>en</default-locale>
            <supported-locale>gr</supported-locale>
        </locale-config>
        <resource-bundle>
            <base-name>languageControl.messages</base-name>
            <var>msg</var>
        </resource-bundle>
    </application>
    <validator>
        <validator-id>passwordValidator</validator-id>
        <validator-class>registration.passwordValidator</validator-class>
    </validator>
    <managed-bean>
        <managed-bean-name>Login_bean</managed-bean-name>
        <managed-bean-class>login.Login_bean</managed-bean-class>
        <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
    </managed-bean>
    <managed-bean>
        <managed-bean-name>sendMail</managed-bean-name>
        <managed-bean-class>common.sendMail</managed-bean-class>
        <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
        <!-- <managed-property> <property-name>email</property-name> <value>#{sendMail.email}</value> 
            </managed-property> -->
    </managed-bean>

    <validator>
        <validator-id>EmailValidator</validator-id>
        <validator-class>registration.EmailValidator</validator-class>
    </validator>

    <managed-bean>
        <managed-bean-name>RegistrationBean</managed-bean-name>
        <managed-bean-class>registration.RegistrationBean</managed-bean-class>
        <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
    </managed-bean>
</faces-config>
```

full web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <display-name>personalSite</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

<filter>
        <filter-name>AuthorizationFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>login.security.AuthorizationFilter</filter-class>
 </filter>
 <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>AuthorizationFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/secure/*</url-pattern>
 </filter-mapping> 

</web-app>
```

Comment: Maybe there is another configuration that's making the strange behavior. Everything looks like its going to work. Additionally, which application server are you using?

Answer (score 0):

are you running this in a debugger?  i'd put a break point at the top of "doFilter()" and see if the filter is even executing.  once you figure out if it's really executing, step through the code (assuming it's filtering) and see why the logic is not performing as expected.  if it's not firing, you can bet it's likely something spurious in the config.

Comment: I am using glassfish 3.1.2 and pretty sure filter is not executing but can't see why.. I'll check your debugging hint to be 100% sure. I have also cleaned project from eclipse/server.. When possible I give you web.xml and faces-config, maybe you can see a flaw I can't

Comment: So finally after load of work.. i noticed i miss the managedbean annotation and filter is somehow working. Question arises now.. isn't filter supposed to work *before* entering the projects.xhtml so to prevent browsing in specific xhtml and not after?
I mean.. when i click on commandbuttons in projects.xhtml i am redirected back to index as should and not when i click on menuitem